# Force user to use only place autocomplete results

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the "*Places*" Google API to make the address input field autocomplete.

The service that the website offers is restricted to a certain area so I restricted the autocomplete filter. The only problem is that the user is not forced to use the google filter but can type in anything.

How do I force the user to select something from the autocomplete filter?

This is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjdo9th6/) of my `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to do *nothing* when the user doesn't select a place from the Place Autocomplete list, then you can simply do this:

```
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);
    }
  });
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6Le7u85/) based off of Google's [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Evan but sadly it doesn't work... The event listener won't be called. And the condition isn't checkable

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. Did you check the jsfiddle? It works just fine. Can you please post your own code in jsfiddle / jsbin / codesandbox / stackblitz so that i can reproduce your exact issue from my side?

Comment: Sorry for a slow response @evan, I will post later a js fiddle with my example but I don't know if it will work for you because I'm using a google key for the API to work on my page.

Comment: That's alright I have my own working API key too so I should be able to test your app just fine. :)

Comment: I have added the JsFiddle in my question. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Thank you, just tried it and it works fine for me with the code I provided in my answer. Check out [this simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h78jL45a/) based off of yours. Type "Bacoli, Metropolitan City of Naples" and select the first Autocomplete result; you'll get an alert. Now type this address again but do not select any place from Autocomplete. Just press the "Enter" key; you won't get an alert, nothing will happen. Maybe I'm not understanding your use case correctly, but isn't this what you want?

Comment: Perfect, I adapted your solution to my code and it works fine!
Thanks a lot for your help and patience :)

Comment: Awesome! Happy to have been of help :)